# PyAthena parses an ARRAY<VARCHAR> column correctly but the result is a string

Tags: dataframe, amazon-athena, pyarrow, python-polars, pyathena

Starting from a single column `abc` of type `ARRAY<STRING>` with one row:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS abc
```

If we execute the query with `pyathena` using the `ArrowCursor`:

```py
cursor = pyathena.connect(**AWS_PARAMETERS).cursor(ArrowCursor)
execution_result = cursor.execute(query)
```

Where the imports and parameters are:

```py
import pyathena
from pyathena.arrow.cursor import ArrowCursor

AWS_PARAMETERS = {
    'aws_access_key_id': ***,
    'aws_secret_access_key': ***,
    'region_name': ***,
    's3_staging_dir': ***,
    'work_group': ***,
}
```

Inspecting the `execution_results`:

```py
execution_result.description
```

It seems that `pyathena` got the column type right as `array`:

```
[('abc', 'array', None, None, 0, 0, 'UNKNOWN')]
```

However, when "materializing" the pyarrow table:

```py
table = execution_result.as_arrow()
```

Unfortunately the column content becomes a `STRING` instead of an `ARRAY<STRING>`:

```
pyarrow.Table
abc: string
----
abc: [["[a, b, c]"]]
```

All I am trying to do here is to get that query result as a Polars (or Pandas) DataFrame with a column of type `ARRAY<STRING>`.

Is there a better and obvious way I am missing here to get the "type right"?

Should I really parse myself that string into a list of strings myself or even convert that string to JSON then to a list of string?

Answer (score 1):

8 months after asking this question the current version of `pyathena-3.0.10` is correctly materializing the arrow table:

```
pyarrow.Table
abc: list<array_element: string>
  child 0, array_element: string
----
abc: [[["a","b","c"]]]
```